# Interesting "bugs" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, adt

Have any of you experienced strange, extremely frequent 'bugs' while developing in Eclipse? Or specifically while developing Android applications?

Another developer on my team has to clean the project several times & build it several times after receiving updates or sometimes on startup.

My issue is similar: Eclipse doesn't seem to detect changes in code / breakpoints unless I clean the entire project first. This just started happening last week. Before that, I really had no issues other than occasionally needing to clean the project.

If others have noticed these strange behaviors, have you found a way to fix them or the reason behind it?

Comment: 1) What version of Java are you using? 2) is "build automatically" checked? (in the "Project" drop down menu at the top)

Comment: No, I build it manually. I'm using java version "1.6.0_25".

Comment: I'm pretty sure Eclipse isn't going to automatically detect code changes unless "Build Automatically" is checked. Unsure about breakpoints, though. I asked about the JRE because back in 1.6.0_14 there was a bug causing breakpoint misses

Comment: Isn't "Build Automatically" just used if you don't want to click "Build Project"? Plus, this just started - I've never used "Build Automatically".

Comment: Yeah, if you are manually clicking "Build Project" then I have no idea what's going on. I haven't used ADT much but have never had problems with Eclipse by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of Eclipse is: When your project is OK, it is mostly OK, too, and problems could be corrected in some easy way. But when you have an error, or more of them, they could cause very unpleasant and unpredictable behavior of the IDE. Of course, it is a big problem, because when you just need IDE for solving **your** problems, you have to solve **its** problems. I have ran across this behaviour many times, for many different problems.

As a receipt I have installed IntelliJ Idea, too. When I feel lost, I check the project on the other IDE. So, at least, I can find **where** the problem is - in IDE or in the project.

Comment: I started using IntelliJ Idea. MUCH better IDE.

Comment: The Eclipse problem is not the Eclipse itself, but the Android plugin. When Eclipse runs pure Java projects, it has *incomparably* less errors.